# Is reversing a string an example of a one to one function?

Tags: functions, word-problem, bit-strings

The word "apple" reversed yields "elppa".
No other input can produce the same output.

And in such a scenario can palindromes also be included in the list of permissible strings.

Was wondering about a non mathematical real world example of a one to one function.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes. No other input can produce the same output. In fact, you also have the fact that any string is an output(since you can just input the reverse string). So this function is actually a bijection.

Comment: Examples here; https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-examples-of-a-one-to-one-function-in-real-life

Comment: In fact, reversing a string is an [involution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)) (applying the function twice always returns you to what you started with).